# uasort that forces one element to the top, the rest properly sorted underneath

Tags: php, cakephp

Is it even possible to sort an array such that one element (in this case, the element matching the current user) bubbles up to the top, while the rest properly sort underneath it?

I tried to do it with this (yeah, I don't get closures in my version of PHP, which is a shame) but had no luck.

```
    uasort($output, create_function('$a,$b',                                                        
        'if( $a["user_id"] == '.$this->user['id'].') { return -1; }'.                               
        'elseif( $b["user_id"] == '.$this->user['id'].') { return -1; }'.                           
        'elseif( $b["percent"] == $a["percent"]) { return strcasecmp($a["username"], $b["username"]); 
        'elseif($a["percent"] < $b["percent"]) { return 1; }'.                                      
        'elseif($a["percent"] > $b["percent"]) { return -1; }'.                                     
        'else { return 0; }'                                                                        
    ));
```

I figure this was the best way to do it, since I have to sort the array anyway - but I'm open to suggestions.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way would probably be to do this:

```
function sortWithUserFirst($output) {
    $user_ids = Set::extract('/user_id', $output); // list of user ids
    $user_id_key = array_search($this->user['id']);
    $user_record = $output[$user_id_key];
    unset($output[$user_id_key]); // clear the key => value pair
    uasort($output, your_sort_function);
    array_unshift($output, $user_record); // put the user record at the beginning of the array
}
```

Comment: Marking as the answer, but I was really hoping there was a way I could do it in one pass. 

I guess I don't really understand the comparison output in the sort? Shouldn't it work so that if I manually ensure when `if ($user_id == 12) return -1` (as an example) that record will just bubble up to the top?

Comment: The problem is because you're checking that both $a['user_id'] and $b['user_id'] equal your target value. think of $a as the outer loop iterator and $b as the inner loop iterator - you are comparing $b against $a, so you should really only check that $a['user_id'] equals your target value, and return 0 when $b['user_id'] does so that the order doesn't change.

Comment: Oh, **that's** how that works! The outer/inner iterator analogy makes perfect sense. Thanks!